# Convert to capital letter the day and month names using PHP strftime()

Tags: php, timezone, strftime

When I want to show the time in the default `timezone` there is no problem, for example:

```
Friday, 12 de December del 2014
```

But the problem exist when I want to show it in other language (other timezone) for example `Spanish`, it outputs like this:

```
viernes, 12 de diciembre del 2014
```

The time format I am using is: `"%A, %d de %B del %Y"`

I would like to show like this: `Viernes, 12 de Diciembre del 2014`

---

I tried to solve it using the `ucfirst()` and `ucwords()` functions, but I think they aren't good solutions for this because it shows like this: `Viernes, 12 De Diciembre Del 2014`

Comment: If nobody has a better solution you could always use `str_replace()`

Comment: @JonathanM First I declared this `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Spanish');` then I call it with `utf8_encode(strftime("%A, %d de %B del %Y"))`

Comment: FYI, months and days of the week are not capitalized in Spanish. That's why it's being output like that.

Comment: @JonathanM In Spanish also are much used capital letters. Every name is capitalized, as a general rule.

Comment: @CésarNontol, yes, people's names are capitalized. Are you sure you want to capitalize days of the week and months? It's not normally done. But if you want it, I'm sure we could get someone to post a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally after searching a magic method that answer my question, I had no other alternative rather than using suggestion of user John Conde.

Here is the method I used:

```
$default_local_date = ucwords(utf8_encode(strftime("%A, %d de %B del %Y")));

$date_connectors_capital = array('De', 'Del');
$date_connectors_lower = array('de', 'del');

$local_date = str_replace($date_connectors_capital, $date_connectors_lower, $default_local_date);

echo $local_date;
```